People-based alarm application centered about doing good things for people
I am looking for an alarm application centered about doing good things for people (reminds you of the person, and prompts you for thoughts or good things to do that will benefit that person that comes up in the alarm).
I am looking for a special alarm app where the alarms can be programmed to come up with the picture of the person your need to think about, and, below, a chronological list, of past things done for that person, when, the alarm, came up, in collapsed mode, with below a list of things you can input, via a round button with a plus sign, of, things, currently thought (to be entered when the alarm goes off, or when you open the app (for the person)), for that person.
You think things, that, can do good for people, and add them (in the forms of thoughts, you may then carry out those actions), for such person among the people the alarms go off for.
Thanks.
